# Converting a number to a string with a maximum of 3 numerals plus SI unit

Tags: javascript, formatting, floating-point

I wrote a function that receives a number as an argument and returns a number (technically, a string) with a maximum of 3 numerals, no matter if there's a decimal separator or not, plus the adequate SI unit. Here some examples for you to understand its logic:

> 0.1 --> 0.1
>
> 42.300099 --> 42.3
>
> 1026 --> 1.03k
>
> 1200000 --> 1.2M
>
> 543760 --> 544k
>
> 34069000000 --> 34.1G

As you can see, it returns a maximum of 3 numerals (for instance, these are acceptable results: `1.23`, `12.3` and `123`, plus any unit).

The function works (as requested in any CR question), but it feels unnecessarily convoluted. Here's the code working in the snippet, with the examples above:

```js
function formatNumber(value) {
  const units = ["", "k", "M", "B"];
  const digits = Math.max(Math.floor(Math.log10(value)), 0) + 1;
  const keep = digits % 3 === 1 ? 2 : digits % 3 === 2 ? 1 : 0;
  const places = ~~((digits - 1) / 3);
  let unit = units[places];
  let number = Math.round((10 ** keep) * value / (10 ** (places * 3))) / (10 ** keep);
  if (number === 1e3) {
    number = Math.round(number / 1e3);
    unit = units[places + 1];
  };
  return number + unit;
};

[0.1, 42.300099, 1026, 1200000, 543760, 34069000000].forEach(e => console.log(e + " --> " + formatNumber(e)))
```

This is for financial data, so I have B for billions instead of the proper SI Giga. Also, since it deals with money, the code right now has no protection for values over 1 trillion (it will return `number + undefined` which is `NaN`), negative numbers and other cases, but I'm aware of that.

Here is the detailed explanation of what I tried to do:

```
function formatNumber(value) {

  //the SI units, changing G for B
  const units = ["", "k", "M", "B"];

  //this gets how many numerals the number has, I found it in this 
  //SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28203456/5768908
  const digits = Math.max(Math.floor(Math.log10(value)), 0) + 1;

  //based on 'digits', this value will be used to determine how many numerals there will
  //be after the decimal point. The remainder is used to calculate it: if we have
  //just 1 numeral inside that SI unit, there's space for 2 more numerals; if we have
  //2, there's space for just 1 more, and if we have 3 there's no space 
  const keep = digits % 3 === 1 ? 2 : digits % 3 === 2 ? 1 : 0;

  //based on 'digits', we get the corresponding SI unit
  const places = ~~((digits - 1) / 3);
  let unit = units[places];

  //using 'keep', this sets by how many powers of ten we'll multiply the number, round it
  //and divide again by such power of ten. That's the same logic of keeping just two
  //decimal places in a long decimal number, when we multiply it by 100, round the result
  //and then divide it by ten again
  let number = Math.round((10 ** keep) * value / (10 ** (places * 3))) / (10 ** keep);

  //because of the rounding up, some cases like 999999 will return 1000k instead of 1M,
  //so I wrote this 'if' condition
  if (number === 1e3) {
    number = Math.round(number / 1e3);
    unit = units[places + 1];
  };

  return number + unit;
};
```

I appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 3):

I found your logic somewhat difficult to follow, especially because the number of significant digits, 3, is hard-coded into many calculations. I came up with a similar but more explicit approach (formatting numbers should not be a performance-sensitive part of your application, I would hope!).

```js
    const defaultUnits = new Map([[1e0, ""], [1e3, "K"], [1e6, "M"], [1e9, "G"]]);

function getUnitValue(value, units) {
    const unitValues = Array.from(units.keys()).sort((a, b) => b - a);
    const absValue = Math.abs(value);
    for (const unitValue of unitValues) {
        if (absValue >= unitValue) {
            return unitValue;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

function checkBase(base) {
    if (base < 0) {
        throw RangeError(`Negative bases, such as ${base}, are not supported`);
    } else if (base - Math.floor(base) > 0) {
        throw RangeError(`Bases with fractional components, such as ${base}, are not supported`)
    }
}

function integerDigitCount(value, base) {
    checkBase(base);
    return Math.max(Math.ceil(Math.log(Math.abs(value)) / Math.log(base)), 1); // leading 0 is one non-decimal place
}

function formatNumber(value, numDigits, base = 10, units = defaultUnits) {
    checkBase(base);
    const initialUnitValue = getUnitValue(value, units);
    const valueToUnit = value / initialUnitValue;
    const nonDecimalPlaces = integerDigitCount(valueToUnit, base);
    const reqdDecimalPlaces = Math.round(numDigits - nonDecimalPlaces);
    const reqdDecimalMultiplier = (base ** reqdDecimalPlaces);
    const valueToUnitSigDigits = Math.round(valueToUnit * reqdDecimalMultiplier) / reqdDecimalMultiplier;
    if (Math.abs(valueToUnitSigDigits) >= base ** numDigits) {
        return formatNumber(valueToUnitSigDigits * initialUnitValue, numDigits, base, units); // recurse if not fully formatted
    }
    const valueString = valueToUnitSigDigits.toString(base);
    return valueString + units.get(initialUnitValue);
}

const sampleTestCases = [0.0, 0.1, 0.434245, 235.5, 0.00001, 42.300099, 1026, 1200000, 543760, 34069000000, 999999, 99999, 999.999, 999.9999999];
function runTests(testCases = sampleTestCases, numDigits = 3) {
    // generate negative testcases as well
    const allTestCases = testCases.concat(testCases.map(testCase => -testCase));
    const results = allTestCases.map(testCase => [testCase, formatNumber(testCase, numDigits)]);
    const numDigitsResult = results.map(result => [result[0], result[1], result[1].replace(/[^\d]/g, '').length]);
    const numDigitsTest = numDigitsResult.map(result => [result[0], result[1], result[2], result[2] <= numDigits]);
    numDigitsTest.forEach(result => console.log(`${result[0]} ---> ${result[1]}; |${result[1]}| = ${result[2]}; ${result[2]} <= ${numDigits} is ${result[3]}`));
    const assertion = numDigitsTest.reduce((acc, x) => (x[3] && acc), true);
    console.assert(assertion);
    return assertion;
}

runTests();
```

Overall, I feel this is a more straightforward approach, where the main idea is:

- we find the largest unit which is less than the provided value,
- express the value in terms of that unit (a quick division by the value of the unit),
- then round off to the required number of significant digits

  - unfortunately involving a calculation of how many decimal places that entails
- if the number of the digits of the number we end up with exceeds the number of significant digits allowed:

  - multiply the rounded-off number in units with the unit value to get back the unitless rounded-off value,
  - run that value through the function again
- with all that done, take the rounded-off number in the appropriate units and concatenate the string representation of that with the appropriate unit suffix, and return that

The ES6 `Map` provides a nice way to group together the unit suffixes and their values, and with this algorithm you have a number of customization points - the choices of units, the base of the representation (10 for decimal, 16 for hexadecimal, etc.), and of course the number of significant digits.

Also, a bunch of `Math.abs` allows us to handle negative numbers in a sane way as well.

Comment: Thanks. The number of digits (3) is hardcoded because that's what I need the function to do, maybe a name like `function formatNumberWith3Numerals` would make that more clear. But it was nice passing that as an argument as well.

Comment: Try with values like 0.0 and values just under a power of 1000 like 999.99, 999.99999.  Still work? I don't use javascript.  This is from a FP standpoint.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica 0.0 gives 0 and the 999.99... ones give 1K. I think that's the expected behavior?

Comment: I know see code's handling of edge cases with `Math.max(..., 1)` and `if (valueToUnitSigDigits >= base ** sigDigits) ...`.  Good!

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica for some reason I decided to look at how well the code handled negative numbers, and turns out, it didn't really. Updated with a bunch of `Math.abs` calls to enable negative number support.